# asp.net login denies anonymous user to see the website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

In my website only authorised users are allowed to see the price list. However, anonymous users are denied access to any page of web site. I could not figure it out.

Comment: Well, how have you implemented authentication on your site? You've given us **nothing** to work with here.

Comment: Is the price list the only page that is restricted in this way?

Comment: Did my answer help you to navigate to the answer? any feedback

Answer (score 0):

In short: something is not configured well in your authentication. One of the solutions would be setting up the Authorize attribute on top of the `Controller` or `ActionResult` that returns the view of prices.

```
[Authorize(Roles="CanAccessPriceList")]
public class AccountController : Controller
```

or the `ActionResult` level code like:

```
[AuthorizeUser(AccessLevels="ReadPrices, UpdatePrices")]
public ActionResult PriceList(int parameter)
{
   // some code...
   return View();
}
```